# Derivation for the interference of two plane waves

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, interference, complex-numbers, superposition

I am trying to understand the derivation for the intensity of two interfering waves. In my textbook, I see this:

[image]

I am confused by everything on the first line, namely:

1. It seems like we are distributing the magnitude operator to the individual wave functions. I don't fully understand why we utilize the complex conjugates here $\psi_{1}^{*}\psi_{2} + \psi_{2}^{*}\psi_{1}$, and where it comes from?
2. How does the previous expression $\psi_{1}^{*}\psi_{2} + \psi_{2}^{*}\psi_{1}$ collapse to 2Re($\psi_{1}^{*}\psi_{2})$?

Considering we can represent waves as vectors in the complex plane, it makes sense that we multiply the complex conjugate when computing the squared magnitude for an individual wave function. But I don't understand how that specifically relates here?

[On Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_interference#Optical_wave_interference), the derivation for such interference is more understandable and doesn't follow this exact derivation here.

Answer (score 0):

The two derivations -- the one in your question and the one on Wikipedia -- are effectively the same.  The wave functions are named $U_1$ and $U_2$ on Wikipedia and $\Phi_1$ and $\Phi_2$ in your question.  If you evaluate any of the functions you get a complex number (*).  Remembering that you can express a complex number in rectangular notation:

$$\Phi_1 = U_1 = a + \mathrm{i}b$$
$$\Phi_2 = U_2 = c + \mathrm{i}d$$

The rest follows directly from the properties of complex numbers:

1. For any complex number $z = x + \mathrm{i}y$:   $\,\,zz^* = (x + \mathrm{i}y)(x - \mathrm{i}y) = x^2 + y^2 = |z|^2$, and therefore $(U_1+U_2)(U_1+U_2)^* = |U_1+U_2|^2$, or equivalently $(\Phi_1 + \Phi_2)(\Phi_1+\Phi_2)^* = |\Phi_1+\Phi_2|^2$.
2. $ {|\Phi_1 + \Phi_2|}^2 = {| (a + \mathrm{i}b) + (c + \mathrm{i}d) |}^2 =
   {| (a + c) + \mathrm{i}(c + d) |}^2 =  (a+b)^2 + (c+d)^2 =$ $ a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + 2(ab + cd) = (a^2 + b^2) + (c^2 + d^2) + 2(ab+cd) = $ $ |a + \mathrm{i}b|^2 +  |c + \mathrm{i}d|^2 + 2(ab + cd) = |\Phi_1|^2 +  |\Phi_2|^2 + 2(ab + cd) $.
3. For any complex numbers $z_1 = x_1 + \mathrm{i}y_1$, $z_2 = x_2 + \mathrm{i}y_2$: $\,\,z_1^*z_2 + z_1 z_2^* = (x_1 - \mathrm{i}y_1)
   (x_2 + \mathrm{i}y_2) + (x_1 + \mathrm{i}y_1)(x_2 - \mathrm{i}y_2)
   = 2(x_1 x_2 + y_1 y_2)$.  Using this result in the last term in (2)
   above: ${|\Phi_1 + \Phi_2|}^2 = |\Phi_1|^2 +  |\Phi_2|^2 + (\Phi_1^*\Phi_2 + \Phi_1 \Phi_2^*)$.
4. For any complex numbers $z_1 = x_1 + \mathrm{i}y_1$, $z_2 = x_2 + \mathrm{i}y_2$: $\,\,z_1^*z_2 = (x_1 - \mathrm{i}y_1)
   (x_2 + \mathrm{i}y_2) = (x_1 x_2 + y_1 y_2) + \mathrm{i}(x_1 y_2 - y_2 y_1)$,
   so that $\mathrm{Re}(z_1^*z_2) = (x_1 x_2 + y_1 y_2)$.  Using this result in the last term in (2) above: ${|\Phi_1 + \Phi_2|}^2 = |\Phi_1|^2 +  |\Phi_2|^2 + 2\mathrm{Re}(\Phi_1^*\Phi_2)$.

(*) Euler's formula: $X \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}y} = X(\cos(y) + \mathrm{i}\sin{y})$.